# What's wrong with this quicksort code (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

This is written in Python3. Here's the code :

```
def partition(arr, l, h):
pivot = arr[l]
i = l+1
j = h
while i <= j:
    print('i is ', i)
    print('j is ', j)
    while arr[i] < pivot:
        i += 1
    while arr[j] > pivot:
        j -= 1
    arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]

# Placing the pivot at its sorted position
arr[j], arr[l] = pivot, arr[j]
return j


def quicksort(arr, l, h):
    if l >= h:
        return arr
    p = partition(arr, l, h)
    print('p is ', p)
    quicksort(arr, l, p-1)
    quicksort(arr, p+1, h)


test = [4, 2, 7, 1]
sorted_test = quicksort(test, 0, len(test)-1)
print(sorted_test)
```

Here's the output -
[image]

According to the error, arr[i] is going out of range but how is the variable "i" reaching that value?
I know there are other ways to implement this but what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like you're increasing `i` until it goes off the end of your list and trying to access `arr[i]`

Comment: @khelwood yes i figured that out. But I don't understand how that is happening. The variable "i" shouldn't reach that value.

Comment: OK. So when you have `while arr[i] < pivot: i += 1`, what would stop `i` reaching that value?

Comment: @khelwood `while i<=j` will ensure that `i` doesn't exceed `j` . And the max value j can hold is `len(arr)-1` Am I thinking in the wrong direction?

Comment: But `while i<=j` isn't going to interrupt `while arr[i] < pivot: i += 1`. The outer loop condition isn't checked again until the next time the outer loop repeats.

Comment: @khelwood yes you're right I just figured it out! Thanks so much! I had a feeling I was doing something very silly

Answer (score 0):

here is code

```
def partition(arr, low, high):
    i = (low-1)         # index of smaller element
    pivot = arr[high]     # pivot
  
    for j in range(low, high):
  
        # If current element is smaller than or
        # equal to pivot
        if arr[j] <= pivot:
  
            # increment index of smaller element
            i = i+1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
  
    arr[i+1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i+1]
    return (i+1)
  
# The main function that implements QuickSort
# arr[] --> Array to be sorted,
# low  --> Starting index,
# high  --> Ending index
  
# Function to do Quick sort
  
  
def quickSort(arr, low, high):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    if low < high:
  
        # pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now
        # at right place
        pi = partition(arr, low, high)
  
        # Separately sort elements before
        # partition and after partition
        quickSort(arr, low, pi-1)
        quickSort(arr, pi+1, high)
  
  
# Driver code to test above
arr = [10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5]
n = len(arr)
quickSort(arr, 0, n-1)
test = [4, 2, 7, 1]
quicksort(test, 0, len(test)-1)

print("Sorted array is:")
for i in range(len(test)):
    print("%d" % test[i])
```